# New content pane (in view) not showing up for adding to panel

Tags: 7, views, panels

Added new content pane as part of my view. Even after saving, and clearing the cache, this pane is not showing up on the available panes list when adding content to Geary type panel/column in Drupal 7. Could this be a configuration issue?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you have to save prior changes to the panel in question. In the list of panels you'll see a padlock icon and a hover-caption of "you have locked this panel, until you save these changes."

Once you save the panel in question, you'll see new content panes that you've created in a View.